# Is it possible to create a global Ejs component?

Tags: javascript, ejs

As you can see I included my navbar component in my index.ejs file and I am doing the same thing with every other file I have, like user page for example. Is there any way that I can use my navbar component in all of my ejs files by including it somewhere once? instead of including it separately in each ejs file?

Right now I am doing this in every one of my files:

**index.ejs:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <% include components/navbar %>

        rest of the code...

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can put your navbar in another file as a layout and use ejs readFile and send the string as a parameter to your pages and include it like a variable

Comment: @BrightFaith Do you mind show me how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you requested in comments , this is my way to do it :
i have "views" folder in project including these folders inside :

- Assets
- Layouts

and dynamic ejs files beside them
let's say we want to render this layout which has a header in each page , but with different body  :

layout :

```
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <% for (let cssLink of cssLinks) { %>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<%= cssLink  %>" />
    <% } %>
    <title>home page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>THIS IS HEADER!</h1>

    <div id="demo">
      <%- mainView %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

you can see there is a variable `mainView` in the body , so let's see how can we insert our dynamic body there :
i have a function inside my utility folder which reduces the repeat of code :

```
const ejs = require('ejs');
const path = require('path');
const layoutsPath = path.join(__dirname, "./../views/layouts/");
const assetsPath = path.join(__dirname, "./../views/assets/");
const viewsPath = path.join(__dirname, './../views/');
const load = (basePath, filename, data, cb = null) => {
    let route ;
    switch (basePath) {
        case 'layout': {
             route = layoutsPath;
             break;
        }
        case 'asset': {
             route = assetsPath;
             break;
        }
        case 'view': {
             route = viewsPath;
             break;
        }
        default: {
             route = basePath;
        }
    }

    ejs.renderFile(path.join(route, filename), data, (err, str) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return err;
        }
        if (cb === null) {
            return str;
        } else {
            return cb(str);
        }

    });
}

module.exports = {
    load
}
```

now in the `index.js` i want to output my `home.ejs` inside my `header.ejs` to the client :

```
let allUsers = await usersModule.findAll();
let renderedHTML = '';
load('view', 'home.ejs', { allUsers }, (rendered) => {
    load('layout', 'header.ejs', { mainView: rendered, cssLinks: ['/css/header.css'] }, (fullView) => {
        renderedHTML = fullView;
    });
});
res.status(200).send(renderedHTML);
```

so here i am getting my required data for my body from database , passing it to the home.ejs , there i loop and render my body view , e.x for home.ejs :

```
    <div>
  <% for (let user of allUsers) { %> 

        <ul>
            <li>email : <%= user.email %></li>
            <li>name : <%= user.name %></li>
        </ul>

    <% } %>
</div>
```

rendered body is passed to our callback as parameter , we can pass it to our header now with variablename `mainView` , so in the header,  the entire rendered body will be insert in the right place in our layout .
now our layout and dynamic body have merged and are ready to be sent to the client

Comment: Thank you so much! it is exactly what I wanted!